# Reading input in bash from stdin

Tags: bash, input, char, stdin

This is my input:

> 99116784 12 12 0 p
>
> 99116784 12 12 0

This is the code i have

```
 while read line || [[ -n "$line" ]];
    do for var in $line 
          do echo $var
       done
 done
```

If I then print $line in the while, the p gets printed
Just doing echo $var doesnt print or know the p is there, anyone knows why?

Comment: The `p` gets printed in this loop. Show more clearly what you are doing, what is the ultimate goal and what command you are running.

Comment: Lacking more information from the OP, I am voting to close as "a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reorganised your code and it works in bash on my Mac.

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line || [[ -n "$line" ]];
do
    for var in $line 
    do
        echo $var
    done
done
exit 0
```

running it

```
./test.sh
99116784 12 12 0 p
99116784
12
12
0
p
99116784 12 12 0
99116784
12
12
0
```